# How to map a postgresql pgarray type to an array type of flink

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-flink

i'm using flink (JDBCInputFormat) to read data out of a postgresql database in a distributed way. JDBCInputFormat requires to specify TypeInformation for all database columns. Postgresql is using special array type PgArray. If I try to use BasicArrayTypeInfo I allways got "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;".
Any ideas how to solve it?

Thanks in advance,
Hannes

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is very similar to this: [Json data cannot be fetched in flink when reading data from postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51078537/json-data-cannot-be-fetched-in-flink-when-reading-data-from-postgresql/51081733#51081733)

I think you should use a `TypeInformation.of(PgArray.class)` instead of `BasicArrayTypeInfo` and convert it manually to an Array in a map stage.